# How to open MIME - "application/x-509-server-cert" type in Android Moto G?

Tags: android, mime-types, x509certificate, motorola

Here is a strange case from Moto G. I am trying to open server certificate file in android programatically and then install it. I am using below code to make it work out. It works for all devices except Moto G and throws toast message saying "Couldn't install because the certificate file couldn't be read". Also another strange thing i found was Moto G finds the MIME type of this certificate file as totally different from other devices :

```
Note 2 - application/x-509-user-cert
Moto G - application/x-509-server-cert
Verizon - application/x-509-user-cert
Samsung Nexus - application/x-509-user-cert
Sony - application/x-509-user-cert
```

How can i then actually open this particular MIME type = "application/x-509-server-cert" in Moto G. For a safer side i am no where hardcoding MIME type and opening it. I am actually letting android to identify and then do whatever it want

```
protected void openFile() {

                File vpnCerti = new File("/sdcard/VPNCertificate/Install.crt");

                //Mime Type Info : http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm

                //Identify MIME types
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(vpnCerti);
                MimeTypeMap type_map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                //Get the extension from the path
                String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path.toString());
                extension = extension.toLowerCase();
                if (extension.contains(".")) {
                    extension = extension.substring(extension.lastIndexOf("."));
                }
                String mime_type = type_map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                Log.d("DownloadManager", "MIME Type : " + mime_type);
                //Identify MIME types ends

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                //i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(vpnCerti), "application/x-x509-server-cert");
                i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(vpnCerti), mime_type);

                startActivity(i);




            }
```

Comment: Just found that this issue is happening in many devices having Android 4.4

Comment: Also if i manually try to install this crt file it will work on Moto G but programatically doesn't work

Comment: Well I am also facing the same issue!